# MySQL Error 111 caused by remote connection

Tags: mysql

This database has been running for years, such that all connections have came from the localhost address.  Recently, I have been using xampp to develop new software, and have been connecting to the database from my own machine without any immediate issues.

However, after several hours of making connections from my own machine, the MySQL server stops working altogether regardless of if I am connecting from my own machine or from the server.  This only happens AFTER successfully making connections from my own machine for several hours, or sometimes days.  I get the following message when trying to login via PHPMyAdmin:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111
```

And the following message when trying to visit previously functional pages:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '...' (111) in '...'
```

And the following when connecting via my own machine:

```
allSQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Unfortunately, the client is on GoDaddy Shared Hosting and I don't have access to the my.cnf.  This problem has worked itself out if I just wait several hours or days before, but I do need to avoid it in the future.

Thanks.  I am not very experienced with database admin work, so my apologies if this is a silly question.